# Can I use an integer texture as if it was normalized?

Tags: opengl

I have a texture that has the format `GL_RED_INTEGER`. This texture has been generated with a compute shader.

I have another shader that I use for debugging that just displays the texture. Since it's an integer texture, I have to declare it in the shader as `usampler2D`. And also I have to divide it by `255.0`, in order to normalize it.

However, I would like to reuse this debugging shader for other non-integer textures.

I though there might be some way to use the integer texture as if it was normalized. Is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remembered [texture views](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTextureView.xhtml) exist in OpenGL. It's important to make sure that the texture has been allocated with `glTexStorage2D` as opposed to `glTexImage2D`; otherwise it's not possible.